# Nested select using laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to find a way to convert this raw SQL into a laravel query builder:

```
SELECT value1,value2 
FROM foo
WHERE id NOT IN(
   SELECT id 
   FROM foo 
   HERE foo.key = 'client_location_id');
```

I've looked through the laravel docks but there isn't any clear outlined way of converting nexted selects into their query builder version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereDoesntHave` function:

```
$c = Foo::whereDoesntHave('fooRelation', function ($query) use ($clientLocationId) {
    $query->where('key', clientLocationId);
})->get();
```

This will work if you set the relationship in `Foo` model, for example:

```
public function fooRelation() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Foo::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's `whereNotIn` operator also accepts functions to nest queries:

```
$result = DB::table("foo")
          ->whereNotIn(function ($query) {
                $query->from("foo as f2")
                      ->where("f2.key", "client_location_id")
                      ->select("id");
          })->select("value1","value2")->get();
```

This will produce the following query (you can verify the query you get if you do a `->toSQL()` instead of `->get()`)

```
select `value1`, `value2` 
from `foo` 
where `id` not in (
     select `id` from `foo` as `f2` where `f2`.`key` = ?
)
```

Of course I could point out that this particular query does not require a nested select but I'm assuming this is just an example.

This being said, the eloquent ORM is a better long term solution if your project is large.